# ACF DateTime/Date Picker : get posts greater than the current date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

here the case :

Date field

```
$start_date = get_sub_field('start_date');
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y', $start_date);
$sdate = $date->format('F j, Y');
```

Current Date in wordpress

```
$current_date = date('F j, Y');
```

I want to make one condition that it shows only fields greater than the current date.

so when I am doing this

```
 if ($sdate > $current_date) { }
```

The results are not as expected as it displays the values of older month also. What I am doing wrong ?Any Help?

Comment: Please try below code and let me know if you any concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code. It can help you

if (strtotime($sdate) > strtotime($current_date)) { }

Comment: and btw am using this format format('F j, Y'). This will not be an issue. right?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be comparing to strings, rather then dateTime objects. So php will order them based on the characters the string starts with.

December 3, 2019 will be considered smaller then Januari 5, 2019, because the D comes first in the alphabeth.

You could fix this (if you want to compare strings rather then the dateTime objects themselves) by formatting them like this: 'Ymd'

You are now comparing numbers starting with the year, then the month with leading zeros and then day with leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
startTimes = 'Your date';
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'   => 'post_type',//Your post type
    'post_status' => 'publish',        
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',                           
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $startTimes, //Please confirm date format with your database
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
);

$pre_date_posts = get_posts($args);

_e('<pre>');
print_r($pre_date_posts); //Your Result
_e('</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#id_name').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date()
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow as below:

Please install [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for generating dynamic fields from the backend.

1. Create a field and name it to the Start date then get that filed in your PHP file like this:

```html
<div class="container">
 <?php
  $sDate = get_field('start_date');
  $currendDate = date('F j, Y');
  if($sDate > $currendDate){
   echo 'Yes, It is greater.';
  }else{
   echo 'No, It is not greater.';
  }
 ?>
</div>
```

I hope it would get the help you out.

See attached screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I already did that but didn't worked .But As Suggested by @kali-spm using strtotime , the results are as expected.